# LGoodDatePicker issues with getDate()

Tags: java, swing, date, netbeans, datepicker

I'm using the LGoodDatePicker with Apache NetbeansIDE 12.2 (https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker), and I need to get the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I'm using this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(datePicker1.getDate());
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `getDate()` of this `DatePicker` returns a `java.time.LocalDate`, **not** a `java.util.Date`. That's actually what the error message tells you, it expects a `java.util.Date` but got something else.
That means you shouldn't try to format it using a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` here:

```java
String date = datePicker1.getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

or define a custom pattern using the method `ofPattern(String pattern)` of the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
String date = datePicker1.getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");
```

In this very case, you can even use the `toString()` method of the `LocalDate` in order to get a `String` in the desired format:

```java
String date = datePicker1.getDate().toString();
```